# Eclipse: Turn off Problems for Linked Folder

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse is displaying 'problems' for a JSP that is in a 'linked folder' from another project. I still want to see problems with JSPs in my project, but would like to filter out the problems from the linked folder.

This is for Helios.

Also, I like to have warnings/errors shown on 'selection' vs on project.

Answer (score 0):

For filtering try Project / Properties / Validation / JSP xxx validator / Settings / Add Exclude Group / Add rule / Folder or file name.

For selection Problems view menu (Ctrl-F10) / Configure Contents... / select configuration / select scope (e.g. on selected elements and its children).

Comment: Good, but not quite. The Add Rule / Folder does not know about linked folders. I have a WebContent and a linked WebContent. I want to filter out the linked one only.